# How can I change gnome terminal font in command line?

Tags: fonts, gnome-terminal

I know how to change gnome's terminal font using the gui [image]

But I would like to do the same using the terminal (automated way). How can I do that ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have just found out that I can do this with `gconftool-2`, e.g. :

```
 gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/font --type string "Ubuntu Mono derivative Powerline 11"
```

Comment: Strange, that didn't work for me. The setting changed, but the terminal font didn't.

Comment: Seems I had to go to profile preferences in the terminal and uncheck 'use system default fixed width font'

Answer (score 6):

To also uncheck the `Use the system fixed width font` checkbox from the command line, use:

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_system_font --type=boolean false
```

Tested on Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.1. Your mileage may vary.